# A Timely Offer (Glass arrows, thieves' guild)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the Ragged Flagon there's a note addressed to Delvin named ['A Timely Offer'](http://www.imperial-library.info/content/skyrim-timely-offer). Apparently there should be a shipment of glass arrows under the docks somewhere - has anyone actually found this mythical shipment, or have I just been wasting my time poking around the docks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: Outside the Mistveil Keep Barracks door (labeled on local map) there are 3 barrels and 1 is labeled Thief cache. It has Glass Arrows and other misc items.

To clarify - you have to enter the Keep Barracks, go up the stairs, then out the door to 'Riften'.  The 'Thief Cache' barrel is up there.

Comment: Thieves caches have a random assortment of levelled items. While they might contain Glass Arrows, they don't necessarily, (and won't at low levels). Additionally, this is not the location described in the note.

Comment: @MildewyTadpole
I found it, but it didnt have the arrows in it D:

Comment: In the thief Cache, I found a potion of Prolonged Invisibility and some lockpicks. No glass arrows :/

Comment: That's just a thieves cache. If you read the book on one of the tables in the cistern written by Mallory, it states that there are caches hidden all over with treasure free to whom ever finds it. I've yet to find the actual mythical shipment of glass arrows.

Comment: something changed, I went there and there are only 2 normal barrels!

Answer (score 4):

As stated in a comment by [LessPop-MoreFizz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3129/lesspop-morefizz), the [currently accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43500/) is wrong.

What they are referring to are the thieves caches in Riften and their location is detailed in this [Arqade answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43332/174247).

The comment by [Aquarius Power](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/45976/aquarius-power) further points to the wiki pages which basically points out that the container is bugged.

As with many bugs in Skyrim, [LimeJello24](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/users/727708) has provided a mod named *A Timely Offer* which attempts to fix it.  This mod is available on Nexus for [SSE](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/5882).